# How to get the nested part of a JSON string into a useable data table

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I can get the top level of data using json_normalize. But when I try to set it for a nested part it returns an error. The json_normalize documentation isn't at all clear on what to put in the record_path and other variables. Under the main tree there is a field called liveData. Under that there is (for example) plays -- allPlays -- runners. I want the 3 fields under runners (movement, details, and credits) in a table, along with whatever key fields from the higher levels are relevant, so it is a relational table. It seems that json_normalize should be the function to make that happen but I can't figure out how.

```
import pandas

URL = 'https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1.1/game/642186/feed/live'

df = pandas.read_json(URL)

df2=pandas.json_normalize(df,record_path="liveData")
```

Comment: `runners` isn't inside `matchup`.

Comment: You are right. I edited it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you looking for (I don't see movement, details, and credits) but `df2=pd.json_normalize(df['liveData'])` will get you the next part.

Comment: @hrokr that worked, thanks. How do I write it to get to the next level (plays) and then the next level (allPlays)? I tried it iteratively like this but it doesn't work:

df=pandas.json_normalize(df['liveData'])

df=pandas.json_normalize(df['plays'])